# Sorting after aggregation in Elasticsearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, aggregation

I have docs with this structure:

```
{
    FIELD1:string,
    FIELD2:
        [ {SUBFIELD:number}, {SUBFIELD:number}...]
}
```

I want to sort on the result of the sum of numbers in FIELD2.SUBFIELDs:

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "a1": {
      "terms": { 
        "field": "FIELD1",
        "size":0
      },
      "aggs":{
        "a2":{
          "sum":{
            "field":"FIELD2.SUBFIELD"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I do this I obtain buckets not sorted, but I want buckets sorted by "a2" value.
How I can do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You almost had it. You just need to add an [`order` property](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order) to your `a1` terms aggregations, like this:

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "a1": {
      "terms": { 
        "field": "FIELD1",
        "size":0,
        "order": {"a2": "desc"}      <--- add this
      },
      "aggs":{
        "a2":{
          "sum":{
            "field":"FIELD2.SUBFIELD"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @ErdalG. the documentation or ordering terms aggregations is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order)

Comment: @Val this is not working when `a2` is a `scripted_metric` aggregation. I used it for my cases that I have to use `scripted_metric` aggregation. I got this error 
`"reason": {
                    "type": "aggregation_execution_exception",
                    "reason": "Invalid terms aggregation order path [totalViews]. Terms buckets can only be sorted on a sub-aggregator path that is built out of zero or more single-bucket aggregations within the path and a final single-bucket or a metrics aggregation at the path end."
                }`

Comment: @saeedzhiany Correct, there's an [open PR](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/15718) and an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8486) about this.

Comment: @Val, is there any alternate for this sort? I really need it

Comment: @saeedzhiany not that I know of. Usually, people sort on the client side. Feel free to ask a new question, maybe someone has an idea.

Answer (score 8):

Brilliant from Val https://stackoverflow.com/users/4604579/val

Basically the same thing, but here's what worked for me to find the largest "size" for each "name", and to show the top 25 largest:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "agg1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name.keyword",
        "order": {
          "agg2": "desc"
        },
        "size": 25
      },
      "aggs": {
        "agg2": {
          "max": {
            "field": "size"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```