# elasticsearch query of group by

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to a result that get top N data from every group after group by & sort. I need a list of that.

Like mysql query:

```
SELECT a.person, a.group, a.age FROM person AS a WHERE
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM person AS b 
WHERE b.group = a.group AND b.age >= a.age) <= 2 
ORDER BY a.group ASC, a.age DESC
```

Can any guys help me? Thx a lot.

Comment: can you add what mappings and queries to ran in with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try nested aggregation and in aggregation you can sort also.
check out this :- [Sorting after aggregation in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30759819/sorting-after-aggregation-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: put size as n and then sort it .. you will get top n :)

Comment: Hi Nikunj, I try your way.But it isn't my want. Can you help me again?
My DSL is:
{"size": 2,"aggs": { "a1": {"terms": {"field": "usertype","size": 4}}},"sort": {"recomend": {"order": "desc"}}}
You can format my DSL, thx.
But I only get 2 result from es. I want to get 2 data from every group, must 8 in total. Can you help me ?It great for me is give me a DSL query. Thx

Comment: can you send me some sample data of ES and sample output you want.
If you are not Comfortable here you can msg me or email me at nikunjaggarwal08@gmail.com.
I will send you DSL for sure.

Comment: Ok, I sended a email to you. Please check your mailbox. Thx a lot

Comment: Hi, @Nikunj Aggarwal. Can you remember my problem? Please send mail to me.Thx a lot.