# Sort term aggregation by script

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to sort the term aggregation results using the script?

Specifically I would like to sort the results based on a division of two aggregated fields (a non-additive click-through ratio).

So far I found couple solutions, neither does what I am looking for:

```
"aggs": {
"myagg": {
  "aggs": {
    /* this CTR is incorrect */
    "calculated_ctr" : { "sum" : { "script" : "try { doc['clicks'].value / doc['impressions'].value } catch(Exception ignored) { return 0; } " } }
  },
  "terms": {
    "field": "publisher_id",
    "order": {
      "calculated_ctr": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```

The above does sort on the calculated field just fine, but the CTR is incorrect. It is calculated on each document level and then summed, problem is we are summing here non-additive ratios.

Second approach:

```
"aggs": {
"myagg": {
  "aggs": {
    "calculated_ctr" : { 
      "scripted_metric": {
          "init_script" : "params._agg.imps = []; params._agg.clicks = []",
          "map_script" : "params._agg.imps.add(doc.impressions.value); params._agg.clicks.add(doc.clicks.value);", 
          "combine_script" : "double impressions, clicks = 0; for (i in params._agg.imps) { impressions += i } for (c in params._agg.clicks) { clicks += c } return [impressions, clicks]",
          "reduce_script" : "double impressions, clicks = 0; for (a in params._aggs) { impressions += a[0]; clicks += a[1];  } return clicks / impressions"
      }
    }
  },
  "terms": {
    "field": "publisher_id",
    "order": {
      "calculated_ctr": "desc" /* throws an error */
    }
  }
```

The above is somewhat better as we get the correct CTR. However, it turns out that sorting on `scripted metric` is not possible:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8486

Comment: would this be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30759819/sorting-after-aggregation-in-elasticsearch

Comment: @EiriniGraonidou I just added couple examples, looks like my use case is a bit more complex than I originally thought due to the non-additive ratios.

Comment: could you also post the mappings? I would like to try it